# How to monitor internal cache in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

One of my api in API Management is configured with internal cache and I want to check how much of it is available. What steps to follow for this?

Answer (score 0):

> API Management is configured with internal cache and I want to check
> how much of it is available

I have followed the below steps to check my internal cache Go to **Operation** select your Operation(Get jobs) and select the following configuration

[image]

After configure this save it and go to **test** and you will see something like below ,then try to send another request  and check the internal trace :

[image]

[image]

Please refer this Microsoft Documentations for : [API Management caching policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies) &  [Add caching to improve performance in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache)

Comment: As I can see in the pricing for developer tier I have 10 MB of cache. Is there a way to know how much of cache memory is occupied and how much of it is available?

Comment: Could you please refer this docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-use-analytics  ,  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/api-management-service-limits.md .